# How to fill $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$ in truth tables?

Tags: logic

I have to complete this truth table:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
P & Q & \neg P & \neg Q  & P \rightarrow Q & \neg Q \rightarrow \neg P \\
\hline
T & T & F & F & T & \\
T & F & F & T & \textbf{F} &\\
F & T & T & F & T &\\
F & F & T & T & T &\\
\end{array}$$

Yet, I don't know how to fill the last one.

Comment: If you know the truth table of $\to$, just use the values you have for $\lnot Q$ and $\lnot P$ in the row.

Comment: $P \rightarrow Q $ and $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$ have the same true table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first row, when both $P$ and $Q$ are true (thus $\lnot P$ and $\lnot Q$ are both false), $P\rightarrow Q$ is true. The truth value of $\lnot Q\rightarrow \lnot  P$ is the same as the truth value of $P\rightarrow Q$ in the last row in which both $P$ and $Q$ are false. Fill the last column with truth tables in the same way you did for the third column.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you filled out $P \to Q$. You wrote $T$ or $F$ based on what the values of $P$ and $Q$ were in the same line.

Now, you write $T$ or $F$ below $\neg P \to \neg Q$ based on what the values of $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$ are in the same line. For example, if $\neg P = \neg Q = T$, then $\neg P \to \neg Q$ is true, just like $P\to Q$ is true of $P=Q=T$.