# how does complicated truth tables work?

Tags: logic

I am discovering logical reasoning and I saw some examples of simple truth tables and I was wondering how do they work when they turned to be a little bit more complicated for propositions such as:

$(\neg p \wedge \neg(p\rightarrow q)$

Comment: A t-t for a formula with two variables is no complicated at all : it has four rows. You need a column for $\lnot p$, one for $\lnot (p \to q)$ and one for the complete formula : the conjunction of the previous two.

Comment: The basic "ingredients" are already present in your previous [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467402/how-to-fill-neg-q-rightarrow-neg-p-in-truth-tables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truth tables are created "inside out". You start with the least complex formulae and advance to the more complex formulae.

Here is a recipe. First, list all the subformulae of your formula except the propositional variables:

- $(\neg p \wedge \neg(p \rightarrow q))$
- $\neg p$
- $\neg(p \rightarrow q)$
- $(p \rightarrow q)$

Sort them such that if one formula is a subformula of another, it stands earlier in the list, and write them into a table like this:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
p & q & \neg p & (p \rightarrow q) & \neg (p \rightarrow q) & (\neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q)) \\
\hline
T & T &  &  &  & \\
T & F &  &  &  &\\
F & T &  &  &  &\\
F & F &  &  &  &\\
\end{array}$$

The ordering reflects that $(p \rightarrow q)$ is a subformula of $\neg (p \rightarrow q)$, which again is a subformula of $(\neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q))$. Plus, because $\neg p$ is a subformula of $(\neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q))$, it's listed earlier. Of course, $\neg p$ could equally well stand as second or third element, too.

Now you can start filling the remaining truth values. Having ordered the formulae, this is easy: You just go from left to right. Begin by inserting the truth tables for negation and conditional:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
p & q & \neg p & (p \rightarrow q) & \neg (p \rightarrow q) & (\neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q)) \\
\hline
T & T & F & T &  & \\
T & F & F & F &  &\\
F & T & T & T &  &\\
F & F & T & T &  &\\
\end{array}$$

Next is the negation of a complex formula. Since you have already 'calculated' the truth values for the formula that is negated, you only have to look them up and, in this case, invert them:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
p & q & \neg p & \mathbf{(p \rightarrow q)} & \neg (p \rightarrow q) & (\neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q)) \\
\hline
T & T & F & \mathbf{T} & F & \\
T & F & F & \mathbf{F} & T &\\
F & T & T & \mathbf{T} & F &\\
F & F & T & \mathbf{T} & F &\\
\end{array}$$

Finally, there is a conjunction. I have highlighted the relevant two columns (for the left and right conjunct); just combine them according to the truth table for conjunction (write 'T' into the last column if both highlighted columns at that line have a 'T', or 'F' otherwise).

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
p & q & \mathbf{\neg p} & (p \rightarrow q)& \mathbf{\neg (p \rightarrow q)} & (\neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q)) \\
\hline
T & T & \mathbf{F} & T & \mathbf{F} & F \\
T & F & \mathbf{F} & F & \mathbf{T} & F\\
F & T & \mathbf{T} & T & \mathbf{F} & F\\
F & F & \mathbf{T} & T & \mathbf{F} & F\\
\end{array}$$

Fin.

Comment: By the way, I know that when something is alwas true, there is a way to write that's it's tautological, yet is there a way to write with logical symbols that something is always wrong?

Comment: Did you think of $\models$ for that? I would not know of another single logical symbol for saying a formula is false in all models; but in first-order logic you could write $\models \neg \alpha$...

Comment: Okay, so I can write: $(p \rightarrow q), \neg (p \rightarrow q) ⊨ \neg(\neg p \wedge \neg (p \rightarrow q))$?

Comment: Oh, that statement is true for (at least) four reasons :-) One reason for this is that the premises are contradictory. Another reason is that $\models \neg (\neg p \wedge \neg(p \rightarrow q))$ alone is also true, because $(\neg p \wedge \neg(p \rightarrow q))$ is always false, as the above truth table shows. A third reason is that $\alpha \models \neg (\beta \wedge \neg \alpha)$ is a valid scheme. And a fourth reason is that $\neg (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \models \neg (\neg \alpha \wedge \gamma)$ is a valid scheme, too.